# Netcat Server Connection Refused

Tags: http, terminal, netcat

Using netcat, I need to create a simple server to respond with simple JSON data.

First I am trying with an HTML page:

```
while true ; do nc -l 8888  < index.html ; done
```

or even more simply:

```
netcat -l 8888 < index.html
```

And then in my browser I do this:

```
http://localhost:8888/index.html
```

I also try to connect using netcat:

```
nc -vz 127.0.0.1 8888
```

Each of these yields a 'connection refused' result:

> localhost [127.0.0.1] 8888 (ddi-tcp-1): Connection refused

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: which os? BSD and GNU/Linux netcats are quite different

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem was resolved.

I had to use

```
netcat -l -p 8888 < index.html
```

This way I can listen to a localport. Now I it is working.

Comment: This solved a big issue for me when two android devices wouldnt communicate with each other. Adding the `-p` fixed it.

Comment: But it is an error to use -l in conjunction with -p: https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc

Comment: @MarvinH. there is a ton of different implementations of `nc` which have incompatible command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the index.html in your browser

```
$ netcat -l 8888 < index.html
```

In your browser use  http://localhost:8888

If this does not work, try to telnet

```
$ telnet localhost 8888
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
 test
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

My index.html just contains the string 'test'. If a connection cannot be established the problem is a network problem.

Comment: Hi. That was what I tried. It doesn't work. It's a simple thing, can't figure why it doesn't work...Thanks anyway

Comment: You ommited the index.html in the browser and it didn't work? It works on my machine. It could be your environment, firewall, network setting ...

Comment: Yes, i've tried it without index.html. What could be the problem then?

Comment: Thanks, I can't really see what is happening wrong. I will try to see if I can resolve this...If anyone else has some idea, I would appreciate.